# How list Git tags based on main branch?

Tags: git

I am creating tags for stable commits and then reference it in my pipeline.
I would like to make sure that I reference only tags based on main branch and not any other feature branches.

I created a script for this purpose but I am lacking one thing which is listing only Git tags based on main branch.
How can I do that?

Comment: You need to share more details with us. Can you share the current script and Pipeline sample with us?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "based on main branch", but perhaps you just want `git tag --merged main`

Comment: @WilliamPursell so simple but I had trouble finding it in the flags. Thanks you Sir!

Answer (score 1):

To find tags that are reachable from a specified commit, use `--merged`.  eg:

```
git tags --merged main
```